# Sort a list of BigDecimals parsed from Strings, while maintainig the order of numbers where the values are equal

Tags: java, sorting, bigdecimal

I'm read in a list of strings that represent numbers in various formats

I'm parsing these numbers to BigDecimals and sorting them.

I then print the numbers back out in their original format.

The problem is that I need to maintain the ordering of numbers that are equal which is not happening in my current code.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
class Solution{

    public static void main(String []args){
        //Input
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String []s=new String[n+2];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            s[i]=sc.next();
        }
        sc.close(); for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++) {
            for (int k = (i + 1); k < n; k++) {
                if (new BigDecimal(s[i]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(s[k])) < 0) {
                    String tempValue = s[i];
                    s[i] = s[k];
                    s[k] = tempValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Input

```
9  
-100  
50  
0 
56.6  
90  
0.12  
.12  
02.34 
000.000
```

Output

```
90  
56.6  
50  
02.34  
.12  
0.12  (Wrong order here)  
0  
000.000  
-100
```

Expected Output

```
90  
56.6  
50  
02.34  
0.12  
.12  
0  
000.000  
-100
```

Solution

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++)  {
         String temp="";
         if(new BigDecimal(s[j-1]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(s[j])) < 0) {
             temp = s[j-1];
            s[j-1] = s[j];
            s[j] = temp;
         }
      }
```

Comment: You need to edit your question. First, you're parsing to `BigDecimal`, not `BigInteger`. Also, you want to maintain the order of items that are *equal*, not *even*. When talking about numbers, "even" and "equal" have distinctly different meanings. Lastly, what you're asking for is called a [stable sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stability-in-sorting-algorithms/). Your selection sort is not a stable sort. You should replace it with a different algorithm. Both insertion sort and bubble sort are stable, and as easy to code as selection sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the selection sort algorithm you're using is not stable. That is, it doesn't ensure that items with equal value maintain their relative order in the list. Consider this simple list of items: `[5.0, 5, 3, 6]`.

If you want to sort that in descending order, then after the first pass of selection sort, you'll have: `[6, 5, 3, 5.0]`. The `5.0` got swapped with `6`. The items `5.0` and `5` are now out of order, and they'll stay that way.

Insertion sort and bubble sort are stable algorithms, which maintain the relative order of equal items. I would suggest using one of those two algorithms in place of your selection sort.

Comment: Correctamundo , was using a really bad sorting algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach, using better **abstractions**. You could use a `Map<BigDecimal, String>`. Map *value*: the string as entered by the user. Map *key*: the BigDecimal object that you get by parsing that string.

Now you just need to sort your Map keys; and when you print those in their sorted order, you use each BigDecimal as key ... so that the map gives you the initial "string" value.

Something like:

```
Map<BigDecimal, String> stringsByValue = new HashMap<>();
stringsByValue.put(...

for (BigDecimal value : Collections.sort(stringsByValue.keySet())) {
  String originalInput = stringsByValue.get(value); ...
```

Maybe that requires some tuning to keep the original order for equal values.

Comment: Yes, fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: `Collections.sort` doesn’t work that way. It doesn’t accept a `Set` and it doesn’t return an iterable result. Besides, if you want to fill a map and iterate it in order, why not use a `TreeMap` in the first place…

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`

> A map of comparable keys to values. Unlike TreeMap, this class uses insertion order for iteration order. Comparison order is only used as an optimization for efficient insertion and removal.

There is a `LinkedHashMap` in java.

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order ...

But it is not ordered.